# Evaluate the double integral of exp(x^2 + y^2) where the solid is the half circle given by x^2 + y^2 <= 4 and x + y >= 0.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

Why is theta bounded by -pi/4 and (3/4)pi?

Comment: The line $x+y=0$ passes through the origin in directions $-\frac14\pi$ and $\frac34\pi$ so angles between these values lie to the northeast of the line.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see, I see. Thank you so much for your help! :)